# Capistrano not restarting Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, sidekiq

I have Capistrano deploying my app to a Ubuntu remote server on a cloud host.  It works except that Sidekiq does not get restarted.  After a deploy new Sidekiq jobs are stuck in the queue until it does finally get restarted.  I currently manually SSH into the machine and run `sudo initctl stop/start workers` which works.  I am not super strong at all with Capistrano and me research so far has failed to find me a solution to this.  I am hoping I am missing something obvious to someone more familiar than me.  Here is the relevant portion of my /config/deploy.rb file:

```
namespace :deploy do
  namespace :sidekiq do
    task :quiet do
      on roles(:app) do
        puts capture("pgrep -f 'workers' | xargs kill -USR1") 
      end
    end

    task :restart do
      on roles(:app) do
        execute :sudo, :initctl, :stop, :workers
        execute :sudo, :initctl, :start, :workers
      end
    end
  end

  after 'deploy:starting', 'sidekiq:quiet'
  after 'deploy:reverted', 'sidekiq:restart'
  after 'deploy:published', 'sidekiq:restart'
end
```

**UPDATE**

From my reply logs:

```
 DEBUG [268bc235] Running /usr/bin/env kill -0 $( cat /home/ubuntu/staging/shared/tmp/pids/sidekiq-0.pid ) as ubuntu@159.203.8.242
 DEBUG [268bc235] Command: cd /home/ubuntu/staging/releases/20160806065537 && ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.2.3" ; /usr/bin/env kill -0 $( cat /home/ubuntu/staging/shared/tmp/pids/sidekiq-0.pid ) )
 DEBUG [268bc235] Finished in 0.471 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you need those configs in your deploy.rb if you have the capistrano-sidekiq gem installed and called in your Capfile.

Make sure you have `require 'capistrano/sidekiq'` in your Capfile or it won't know to call the default tasks.

Comment: It was simple - I was missing the `require 'capistrano/sidekiq'`.

Comment: Hmmm... still not restarting - I thought it was by my queue just loads up with jobs until I manually restart.

Comment: I am not sure whats going on - perhaps sidekiq is crashing... just ran another deploy and the queue seems to work now.